# Docker cannot connect application to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run integration tests (in python) which depend on mysql. Currently they depend on SQL running locally, but I want them to depend on a MySQL running in docker.

Contents of Dockerfile:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3:4.3.1
WORKDIR /opt/workdir
ADD . /opt/workdir
RUN python setup.py install
```

Contents of Docker Compose:

```
version: '2'

services:
   mysql:
     image: mysql:5.6
     container_name: test_mysql_container
     environment:
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
       - MYSQL_DATABASE=My_Database
       - MYSQL_USER=my_user
       - MYSQL_PASSWORD=my_password
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     expose:
       - "3306"

   my_common_package:
     image: my_common_package
     depends_on:
       - mysql
     restart: always
     links:
       - mysql

volumes:
  db_data:
```

Now, I try to run the tests in my package using:

```
docker-compose run my_common_package python testsql.py
```

and I receive the error

> pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'localhost' ([Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)")

Comment: What do you have in testsql.py that you think should connect to the docker container of mysql?

Comment: You need to connect using the `mysql` hostname, not localhost. You can think of containers as virtual machines when it comes to networking,

Comment: In the testsql.py module I simply have a line that uses python to connect to a mysql instance on 'localhost' port '3306'

Comment: @andrew see answer below

Comment: @andrew If you have any more issues after reviewing my answer, just reply to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

docker-compose will by default create virtual network were all the containers/services in the compose file can reach each other by an IP address. By using `links`, `depends_on` or network aliases they can reach each other by host name. In your case the host name is the service name, but this can be overridden. (see: [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#links))

Your script in `my_common_package` container/service should then connect to `mysql` on port `3306` according to your setup. (not `localhost` on port `3306`)

Also note that using `expose` is only necessary if the Dockerfile for the service don't have an `EXPOSE` statement. The standard mysql image already does this.

If you want to map a container port to `localhost` you need to use `ports`, but only do this if it's necessary.

```
services:
   mysql:
     image: mysql:5.6
     container_name: test_mysql_container
     environment:
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
       - MYSQL_DATABASE=My_Database
       - MYSQL_USER=my_user
       - MYSQL_PASSWORD=my_password
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     ports:
       - "3306:3306"
```

Here we are saying that port 3306 in the mysql container should be mapped to localhost on port 3306.

Now you can connect to mysql using `localhost:3306` outside of docker. For example you can try to run your `testsql.py` locally (NOT in a container).

Container to container communication will always happen using the host name of each container. Think of containers as virtual machines.

You can even find the network docker-compose created using `docker network list`:

```
1b1a54630639        myproject_default             bridge              local
82498fd930bb        bridge                        bridge              local
```

.. then use `docker network inspect <id>` to look at the details.

Assigned IP addresses to containers can be pretty random, so the only viable way for container to container communication is using hostnames.